# Regex for matching a phrase followed by certain numbers followed by certain string

Tags: r, regex

Another regex problem I can't solve. :/

I have the following input vector:

```
x <- c("test", paste0(rep(paste0("Q18r", c(1:14, 997)), each = 2), c("c1", "c2")))
```

I now want to do the following match:

- Find the phrase "Q18r" that is
- followed by any number of 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 997 that is
- followed by the phrase "c1"

The problem is that I can't figure out how to add the "c1" at the end, i.e. I get it working at least for the first two matches with:

```
stringr::str_subset(x, "Q18r(?=[1-3]|1[1-2])|(997)")
```

I tried a lot of different c1 matches, i.e. `(?=c1)`, only `c1`, `(c1)` etc. but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `"Q18r(?:[1-3]|1[1-2]|997)c1"`? It will output `[1] "Q18r1c1"   "Q18r2c1"   "Q18r3c1"   "Q18r11c1"  "Q18r12c1"  "Q18r997c1"
`

Comment: Nice, hat's exactly what I need. Can you explain a bit on this ?: instead of ?= usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
stringr::str_subset(x, "Q18r(?:[1-3]|1[1-2]|997)c1")
[1] "Q18r1c1"   "Q18r2c1"   "Q18r3c1"   "Q18r11c1"  "Q18r12c1"  "Q18r997c1"
```

*Regex details*:

- `Q18r` - a fixed `Q18r` string
- `(?:[1-3]|1[1-2]|997)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) matching `1`, `2`, `3`, `11`, `12` or `997`
- `c1` - a `c1` string.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't understand thsi "non-capturing" part, because we are matching the numbers and it's not optional?

Comment: @deschen It is not optional, non-capturing means it does not store the submatch in memory. It is only used to group alternative subpatterns.

Comment: Ah ok, so it means sth. like "we have three potential groups: "1, 2, 3"; "11, 12"; "997", right?

Comment: @deschen Yes, that is right.